# How to fully specify the type of a returning parameter in method?

Tags: parameters, abap

I've got a method that imports a structure, creates an internal table out of the structure, and returns this table.

I've implemented it as an exporting method, but now I want to do it as a returning parameter.  Part of the idea is that I don't know anything about the structure being passed till runtime so I'm using a fair amount of generics.  However, "Returning" methods don't like generics.

```
method Parameters:
  Importing struct_data TYPE any 
  Returning table_data TYPE STANDARD TABLE 

method STRUCT_TO_TABLE_R.

  FIELD-SYMBOLS:
    <f_fs>    TYPE any,
    <table>   TYPE STANDARD TABLE .

  DO.

    ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF STRUCTURE struct_data TO <f_fs>.

    IF NOT sy-subrc EQ 0.
      EXIT.
    ENDIF.

    APPEND <f_fs> TO <table>.

  ENDDO.

  table_data = <table>.

endmethod.
```

what do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Your code sample does not really make any sense (besides the formatting issues) - PARAMETERS has nothing to do with methods, so the method signature is missing. Besides, for a Q&A format, it's not relevant that you're a "noobie learning abap". Could you perhaps try to clarify the problem a bit?

Comment: You have pretty much answered your own question though, to fully specify a parameter you have to tell it the exact type, you can't use type ANY, CLIKE or any other generic type.  So you can't use a generic type as a returning parameter.

Comment: Just in case anyone searches for the German error message: _"RETURNING-Parameter müssen vollständig typisiert sein."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning parameters are passed by the Value. In other words, when the method is being executed, you can always access the returning parameter but your callers can omit receiving the values from the method at all, but the method still has to use the parameter. That would be reason you need to specify fully TYPED type for returning.

As alternative, you can convert your table to Object reference and pass it back to the caller.

```
class lcl_Test DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
   methods: to_Table
            returning value(ro_tab) type ref to data .
ENDCLASS.  
*
class lcl_Test IMPLEMENTATION.
  method to_Table.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.
```

Regards,

Answer (score 19):

Maybe it's late for a proper response, but I faced the same problem minutes ago.

In order to send an internal table as a RETURNING parameter you need to define a table fully typed in the class.
Here is a sample code of a public section of a class:

```
PUBLIC SECTION.
    TYPES:
      type_table_A TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF T001, //<----- NOT FULLY SPECIFIED
      type_table_B TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF T001 WITH DEFAULT KEY. //<---- FULLY SPECIFIED
```

In terms of standard table:

TYPE_TABLE_A can be as a parameter only for EXPORTING, IMPORTING and CHANGING parameters.

TYPE_TABLE_B can be used in all possible kinds of parameter in the signature of a method, mainly RETURNING.

So as a good practice, you can decide for declaring fully specified standard table types.

Kind regards,

César Scheck

Comment: Thanks! I was getting a "Field symbol must either be fully typed or have the generic type C, N, P, or X" error while doing an "ASSIGN... CASTING" operation. I didn't know what was wrong; but of course as your answer indicates, I needed to define the keys to get a "fully typed field symbol".

Comment: Thank you so much! This was impossible to find elsewhere

Comment: The real answer!